# removing images by specific domain

Tags: jquery-selectors

I am parsing an RSS feed that has images.  Unfortunately, the feed's contents also contain unneccessary 1px x 1px gif images and when I apply css float, margins and padding to the images in the feed, this is also applied to the phantom spacer image upsetting the layout. All of these images originate from feedburner.com. So i am trying to add a class to those images to remove them from the document flow using the following:

```
$(function(){
  $('img[src*="feedburner.com"]').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('remove');
  }
});
```

This is an actual sample image link:

```
<img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/somefeedslink/~4/C5PbADF9rxo" height="1" width="1">
```

Am I doing something wrong? I've tried several methods but this seems to be the most likely method to isolate these images from the rest.  Appreciate any help on this. Thanks

Comment: Are you having trouble isolating the images, or removing them?

Comment: try using .match() and regex expressions with jquery

Comment: There is a pool of images, but the ones i want to remove all have a common source url from feedburner.  I seriously suck at regex...lol.

Comment: As grc pointed out you forgot to close your inner function. And as Rahul said if you are going to apply the same command on all of them you can skip the .each() call.

Comment: That did it! Thank you! I'm a dork and forgot to close the inner function...lol. 2 hours later...  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to flag the images to skip them during parsing later?

```
$('img[src*="feedburner.com"]').addClass('ignore')
```

should do

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked for me. You're just forgot to close a bracket.

```
$(function(){
    $('img[src*="feedburner.com"]').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('remove');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img[src*="feedburner.com"]').remove();
```

Comment: I had to try this one just to see if it would work, but i'm afraid it does not, however the previous answer resolved my issue.